# while passing 2 parameters are month and Year how to club by '/'

Tags: sql-server-2008

my problem is While passing 2 parameters month and year of varchar datatype,i need to club two by '/' and i need to compare with a coloumn(month/year) and then have to show in SQL server. can any one please help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: if you mean concatenate then this will do : select @month + '/' + @year;

Comment: thanks sir. but i need to compare with a coloumn(month/year)..so i need to club those parameters

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? You are passing those parameters to a stored procedure and you want to compare them with a varchar column in a table that has values like 'January/2014', 'February/2014', etc?

Comment: @Amar Duplantier:YES SIR BUT LIKE '01/14','02/14'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example table I created :

```
Create table SampleTable (Id numeric(10,0) identity(1,1) primary key, MonthAndYear varchar(7));
Insert into SampleTable values('01/14');
Insert into SampleTable values('02/14');
```

And the stored procedure :

```
Create procedure compareMonthAndYear
@month varchar(2),
@year varchar(2)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select * from SampleTable s
    where s.MonthAndYear like (@month + '/' + @year)
END
```

Run the stored procedure like :

```
compareMonthAndYear '02','14'
```

Hope you could get an idea!